# Javascript cookies not generated

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I am trying to implement this: http://adaptive-images.com/ into a website.
It will rely on JS-Cookies that will get the screen's resolution so the PHP script that adapts the image sizes knows what resolution to deliver.
Unfortunately it somehow fails to set the cookie (and falls back to 480 resolution...) and I have no idea why. What it does is simply:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.cookie='resolution='+Math.max(screen.width,screen.height)+'; expires=; path=/';
</script>
```

right in the head of the document. Yet, the cookie never seems to be set, I will only see (they should appear in the Resources Part of the Chrome DevTools, right?) the GoogleAnalytics-created ones (yet, this does not seem to be the problem as removing GA makes no difference).

I never used JS cookies before, but from what I can read on the web the syntax seems to be perfectly fine and also I do not get any kind of error messages in the console or elsewhere, it just seems to ignore the cookie setting action.

A long story short: I have no idea what's going on here?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Maybe this is a PHP sided problem so I'll add this part too.
What happens is the following:

First off:

```
$resolutions   = array(1920,1382, 992, 768, 480);
```

Then:

```
  if (is_numeric($_COOKIE['resolution'])) {
    $client_width = (int) $_COOKIE["resolution"]; 

    rsort($resolutions); 
    $resolution = $resolutions[0]; 

    foreach ($resolutions as $break_point) { 
      if ($client_width <= $break_point) {
        $resolution = $break_point;
      }
    }
  }
```

Yet, the script will aways return a 480 resolution, even though my screen is 1920? As far as I get the code it should be returning 1920 so I guess it seems to use the fallback in case `$_COOKIE['resolution']` is not set, which would be going back to 480.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not setting an expires time makes your cookie a session cookie so it only lasts for the lifetime of the browser session (it is not written to disk).

Other than that, your cookie seems to work for me.  When I use that code in a jsFiddle and look in the Chrome debugger at the cookies, I see the cookie string with an item in it for resolution and it's marked as a session cookie, not a permanent cookie.

Perhaps you can describe how you are reading the cookie?

It occurs to me that you're setting the cookie on the client so the server will not see the cookie until the NEXT page requested on that domain.  The server won't see it for the first page.  Could this be your issue?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about session cookies not appearing in the debugger! I added the PHP to the question.

Comment: Session cookies do appear for me in the Chrome debugger.  I don't know PHP so I can't really comment on your PHP.

Comment: I added another possibility to the end of my answer.

Comment: I was thinking of that too, yet there's a comment in the code stating: _only required to work around a bug where some browsers can't set the cookie fast enough on the first visit to the
         website. Such browsers therefor act as though no cookie was set on the very first visit. This means we can't
         allow them to have $mobile_first set to TRUE, or else they get the mobile version on the first load of the site_. I do not have any experience with JS cookies so I cannot really tell.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand how cookies work.  A cookie that is set client-side will NEVER be seen by the first request.  Cookies are sent to the server by the browser with the original http request for the page.  Thus, the JS in the page itself can't cause a cookie to get sent to the first http request to that server because the cookie doesn't exist at that time.  Subsequent requests to that server will see a cookie generated in the first page, but not the first request.

Comment: That's actually how I always thought that cookies are working, yet the image resizer I was trying to implement (I cancelled that as it's not working) is trying to use this mechanism... See: http://adaptive-images.com/ By now I built a similar resizer myself that is working just fine. Thanks!